# How to verify if GDT is set properly?

Tags: operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling, keyboardinterrupt

IDT and GDT for my OS are not working as a whole. I don't know which one of them are not set properly. So can i verify if GDT is set properly so that i may be able to figure out, where the something is wrong.

I am doing this in C.

Comment: I don't think there is specific code to verify a GDT, since you set it yourself. You will have to either examine your code for bugs, or examine the GDT itself for invalid data.

Comment: i know that there is no specific method. But may be an indirect way to check it. That is because i am doubtful whether it has been set up properly as there can be mistakes done while passing the pointer's address from c to assembly etc even if the data of gdt is correct

Comment: Well, if you can't check it with code, what 'indirect method' might you be thinking of?

Comment: no idea. Thats where i requested some help. Just like for  checking a20 line is enabled or not i heard that by comparing the boot signature with some value after some position in memory with value more than 1 mb can be done. So i thought that there might be such indirect ways to verify.

Comment: For the A20 line: http://wiki.osdev.org/A20_Line